# ctx = player.ctx AttributeError: 'Player' object has no attribute 'ctx'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Im making a music bot but i get

```
AttributeError: 'Player' object has no attribute 'ctx'
```

when i do >>play some music when another music is playing (supposed to be for queue)

full error

```
Bot Online
Node <8d0e8f15e4723f72> is ready
Ignoring exception in on_wavelink_track_end
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/catiganvien3/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/catiganvien3/scripts/WaveLinkBot/main.py", line 28, in on_wavelink_track_end
    ctx = player.ctx
AttributeError: 'Player' object has no attribute 'ctx'
```

Full code is

```py
import wavelink
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import os

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='>>')


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Bot Online')
    bot.loop.create_task(node_connect())


@bot.event
async def on_wavelink_node_ready(node: wavelink.Node):
    print(f'Node <{node.identifier}> is ready')


async def node_connect():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    await wavelink.NodePool.create_node(bot=bot, host='ash-01.thermalhosting.com', port=2008, password='ASH-01')


@bot.event
async def on_wavelink_track_end(player: wavelink.Player, track: wavelink.Track, reason):
    ctx = player.ctx
    vc: player = ctx.voice_client
    if vc.loop:
        return await vc.play(track)
    try:
        next_song = vc.queue.get()
        await vc.play(next_song)
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title="Now playing", description=f'Song name: **{next_song.title}**\nSong author: **{next_song.author}**')
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    except:
        # An exception when after the track end, the queue is now empty. If you dont do this, it will get error.
        await vc.stop()
@bot.command()
async def play(ctx: commands.Context, *, search: wavelink.YouTubeTrack):
    if not ctx.voice_client:
        vc: wavelink.Player = await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect(cls=wavelink.Player)
    elif not getattr(ctx.author.voice, 'channel', None):
        await ctx.send(f'Connect to a voice channel to use this command!')
    else:
        vc: wavelink.Player = ctx.voice_client
    song_name = search.title
    song_author = search.author
    if song_author == None:
        song_author = 'Unknown'
    # embed = discord.Embed(title="Added to queue", description=f'Song name: **{song_name}**\nSong author: **{song_author}**')
    # await vc.play(search)
    # await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    if vc.queue.is_empty and vc.is_playing:
        await vc.play(search)
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Playing", description=f'Song name: **{song_name}**\nSong author: **{song_author}**')
        return await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    else:
        await vc.queue.put_wait(search)
        embed = discord.Embed(title="Added to queue", description=f'Song name: **{song_name}**\nSong author: **{song_author}**')
        return await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    vc.ctx = ctx
    setattr(vc, "loop", False)
@bot.command()
async def pause(ctx: commands.Context):
    if not ctx.voice_client:
        return await ctx.send('Im not playing any music!')
    elif not getattr(ctx.author.voice, 'channel', None):
        await ctx.send(f'Connect to a voice channel to use this command!')
    else:
        vc: wavelink.Player = ctx.voice_client
    await vc.pause()
    await ctx.send(f'Paused!')

@bot.command()
async def resume(ctx: commands.Context):
    if not ctx.voice_client:
        return await ctx.send('Im not playing any music!')
    elif not getattr(ctx.author.voice, 'channel', None):
        await ctx.send(f'Connect to a voice channel to use this command!')
    else:
        vc: wavelink.Player = ctx.voice_client
    await vc.resume()
    await ctx.send(f'Resumed!')

@bot.command()
async def stop(ctx: commands.Context):
    if not ctx.voice_client:
        return await ctx.send('Im not playing any music!')
    elif not getattr(ctx.author.voice, 'channel', None):
        await ctx.send(f'Connect to a voice channel to use this command!')
    else:
        vc: wavelink.Player = ctx.voice_client
    await vc.stop()
    await ctx.send(f'Stopped!')

@bot.command()
async def disconnect(ctx: commands.Context):
    if not ctx.voice_client:
        return await ctx.send('Im not playing any music!')
    elif not getattr(ctx.author.voice, 'channel', None):
        await ctx.send(f'Connect to a voice channel to use this command!')
    else:
        vc: wavelink.Player = ctx.voice_client
    await vc.disconnect()
    await ctx.send('Bye!')

@bot.command()
async def loop(ctx: commands.Context):
    if not ctx.voice_client:
        return await ctx.send('Im not playing any music!')
    elif not getattr(ctx.author.voice, 'channel', None):
        await ctx.send(f'Connect to a voice channel to use this command!')
    else:
        vc: wavelink.Player = ctx.voice_client
    try:
        vc.loop = True
    except Exception:
        setattr(vc, "loop", False)
    if vc.loop:
        return await ctx.send('Loop is now enabled!')
    else:
        vc.loop = False
        return await ctx.send('Loop is now disabled')

@bot.command()
async def queue(ctx: commands.Context):
    if not ctx.voice_client:
        return await ctx.send('Im not playing any music!')
    elif not getattr(ctx.author.voice, 'channel', None):
        await ctx.send(f'Connect to a voice channel to use this command!')
    else:
        vc: wavelink.Player = ctx.voice_client

    if vc.queue.is_empty:
        return await ctx.send('Queue is empty!')
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Queue")
    queue = vc.queue.copy()
    song_count = 0
    for song in queue:
        song_count += 1
        embed.add_field(name=f"Song number {song_count}", value=f"{song.title}")

    return await ctx.send(embed=embed)
bot.run('secret')
```

Comment: Because the class `wavelink.Player` doesn't have an attribute `ctx`? Try to get the context in some other way. If you just want the `voice_client`, try using `player.user`. Or, get the context when the `play` command is used, and store it somewhere so you can use it in your `on_wavelink_track_end`. See [`wavelink.Player`](https://wavelink.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wavelink.html#player).

Comment: @TheAmateurCoder player.user does not work `vc: player = ctx.voice_client
AttributeError: 'ClientUser' object has no attribute 'voice_client'`

Answer (score 1):

If I'm right, **it should be a version issue. There is nothing wrong with your code.**
I didn't have this troble until I *re-installed* wavelink, so I do prefer it's a version issue, I don't know which version has this ctx value, but if I find the correct version I'll answer you!

## EDIT

The version has `player.ctx` is 1.2.5, I am not sure if 1.3.0 still has the `player.ctx` but I do prefere 1.2.5 because it's a more stable version (for me).

#### To install

`python3 -m pip install wavelink==1.2.5`, `python -m pip install wavelink==1.2.5`
or
`py -m pip install wavelink==1.2.5`, depends on your machine. You could also try version 1.2.3

#### IMPORTANT

It could be also that **the bot stayed too long in the call** and wavelink can't get the ctx out of it.